# Something is wrong with my if and else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Here is my code:

```
var points = 10

if(points == 10) {

points + 200;

}

else if (points === 100) {

points + 10;


}

console.log(points)
```

What happens is that it logs 10, when what i would like to happen is that it logs 210. Any idea on what i have done wrong? I got some feedback on it on an earlier question, but it still does not seem to work.

Comment: you need an assignment of the expression. `points = points + ...`

Comment: `points + 10;` ---> `points = points + 10;` or `points += 10;`

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I am just learning javascript and i find it quite diffucult. It's really nice that people like you guys can help me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we use assignment operator we have to use like this:

points = points + 200

so in your code at line "points  + 200" or "points + 10" have not changed the value of variable points at all. So, variable points is the same as the first line (var points = 10)

You might modify your program like this:

var points = 10

if(points == 10) {

//points = points +200

points + 200;

}

else if (points === 100) {

//points = points + 10

points + 10;

}

console.log(points)